# New iTunes Connect can't select my app build in Processing Status

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, application-loader

On **new iTunes Connect** after upgrading **Xcode to 7.0** version I can't select my build after uploading it from Xcode.

Hanged on weird **(Processing)** Status as you may see in the picture below.
And **it keeps unselectable**.

Thanks.

[image: Build can't be selected]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about iTunesconnect not programming, however I can say that processing times have been quite long at times lately. I am not sure if this is the extra processing required for bitcode or they are running more extensive security analysis and scanning but patience is the key.

Comment: You have to wait until it finishes processing. Last week it took one of my apps about 20 hours to finish even though it normally takes 20 minutes.

Comment: Voting to leave open, as iTunesConnect processing is as much a part of the iOS programming process as a linker is.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a problem related with Xcode 7 or the new iTunes Connect I think, it happened before but now I see it happens more often (based on the questions in these days on StackOverflow); some months ago I had my build stuck in processing for over 6 days.

I know this it's terrible but **normally this processing state if happens it takes 20 minutes about** and after that you can select you build.

If you have problems or the process takes too much time you can [contact Apple](https://developer.apple.com/contact/).

Comment: Or try to make a new build ( increase just build number for example, in Project > Identity > Build ) and try to upload again, it sometimes gets stuck and new build is processed faster.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem many times, it was a time sensitive app I needed to get online, I re-archived my app in Xcode with a higher version, and uploaded it to the app store, when doing this, my build was no longer processing and I could select it (the new one was processing but the original version that I wanted was then available) it's very annoying to have to re-archive and upload another identical version, but it was the only way I found to get a build out of processing quickly.

I hope this helps!

Beau